# Meaning of the phrase "loaded topic"

Tags: meaning

I have looked up all the meanings of "loaded" in dictionaries, but still confused what that means. Here is the context it was used in:

> Racism is a loaded topic and issue.

Does that mean that racism is a topic that is difficult to talk about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**loaded** is a colloquialism that means complicated and potentially divisive, something that causes emotion to run high. Use of the term could imply that the speaker considers the topic one to be avoided.

> That's a loaded topic, let's not go there.